# 93 Seca 2 won't start without a jump, battery good?

Tags: motorcycle, battery, starter, power, charging

So i have taken the battery out and had it tested at autozone and they said the battery was fine. the solonoid is fine because if i hit the starter the motor starts to act like it wants to turn but sounds like the battery is half dead. I replaced the starter motor and it did not help, skipped the relay system and it did not help either. Is it just the battery and autozone mis read it? i hoocked it to my multimeter and it failed a load test, 12.86 v standing and dropped to 3.6 under load. Is this a bad cell, wondering why autozone isnt picking it up? just wanna make sure theres nothing else it could be besides the battery/

Comment: Test with a known good battery - if it starts properly then it is the old battery, if it does not start then something else is at fault.

Comment: Unless you try with a known-good battery, as @SolarMike suggests, you're just guessing. Remember too that if the battery is bad, you don't know _why_ it's bad, whether from age or because the bike's charging system isn't working properly. In any event, you must start the diagnosis and repair by assuring that the battery installed in the bike is healthy and fully-charged.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the battery is completely dead to me (not just 1/2 dead, as you say ;-). I think your voltage drop during testing is pretty telling.

Several things to look at, one of them being what Solar Mike put in the comments. If you have known good battery, try it and see if everything works. If it does, the battery is confirmed dead. You could try to bring it back to life using a charger. It's at least worth a try.

Something else to consider. The lifespan of a regular battery is about 5 years. If your battery is past this age, it's most likely due to be changed anyway. Use this as a litmus when considering replacing the old battery.

You can also take the battery to a different place and have them load test it. Many places will do this for you for free. Just realize, some of the people who staff these places aren't what I'd call "qualified" mechanics, meaning they don't have a clue. They're just working a job.

Comment: I took a battery to an auto parts store for testing. They used a conductive tester. They had had not the knowledge how to use it. When it came time to select the battery CCA spec., He said out loud that it didn't matter. He "diagnosed" my bad battery as good.

Comment: @Jupiter if he said the CCA didn’t matter then go to a different aka better store.